# Shadowing RDP session automatically

Tags: powershell, server, remote-server, remote-desktop

I want to create a powershell script. One of our supporting companies needs to connect to our server from time to time to make their work and I need to connect their RDP session to watch them if their doing is OK.

Server: MS Server 2012 R2 x64

The case is I want to create a script which;

1- Checks the server's current sessions
2- Finds the specific session ID come from the username (the which I will give them to connect) currently logged in as RDP
3- When I pull the correct session ID from the username (and that means he is currently online and connected), I want to shadow his/her session without prompting/requesting their approvals.

Yes, I can do these separately but looking a powershell script or something like that to these. In one attempt, I want to shadow rdp to correct session and if he/she is not online, I want the system return an information message to me that the username is not currently online.

Is it possible?

Thanks&Regards 
Melih

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves PoSh does not natively supports querying RDP sessions (unless using the RDS broker, but I could be wrong here) but you can easily do that via [query session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/query-session)

I cannot test it right now but something like this should do the trick:

```
C:\>query session
  SESSIONNAME USERNAME       ID STATE  TYPE    DEVICE
  console     Administrator1 0  active wdcon
  rdp-tcp#1   User1          1  active wdtshare
  rdp-tcp                    2  listen wdtshare
```

You can even call it with the username directly if that is known to you.

Shadowing the session would be easily accomplished with something like

```
mstsc /v:"$srv" /shadow:"$id" /control /noconsentprompt
```

I did not test this so maybe it needs some tweaking but a possible starting point could be

```
$userSessions = query session user01 /SERVER:server01 | Select-Object -skip 1 | ForEach-Object{$_.Split(' ',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)}
$sessionId = $userSessions[2]

mstsc /v:"$srv" /shadow:"$sessionId" /control /noconsentprompt
```

Of course if running from the local server you can omit the /SERVER:XXX argument.

Hope this can help getting you started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try this and give you the results,

Comment: I tried your script but it didn't work even if it seems OK for me. When RDP (mstsc) screen pop-ups, it tries to connect to session ID number instead; "/shadow:11"

Btw, this session ID OK and correct ! It pulls the correct ID but I couldn't understand why it sees it as a server.

Any other tips on this? Thanks

Comment: Hmm have just tried and apparently got a pair of extra double quotes, this worked on one of my servers `mstsc  /shadow:$sessionId /control /noconsentprompt`

Comment: Did you try this script from your local computer or in made RDP session? Because I am tried it from my local computer and I need to know if I should start this script from the server, thanx..

Comment: Both.  I shadowed a session on a remote server and one on the same server, if you omit the /v: command will assume session is on the local server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and great help. It's working at both platforms. Cheers